# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Example usage of WLCookieExtractor

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst

We're writing a hybrid Worklight application and would like to find out how the `WLCookieExtractor` class is used inside an Android app.

There is virtually no documentation on usage, the only thing I've found is [this page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android/html/index-files/index-15.html) which simply states the class' purpose.

Basically, we have an HTML component which currently connects to the Worklight Server and can invoke (protected) procedures, but we'd like to share the session with other functionality written in native code, inside the same application.

If anyone could shed some light on this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that in your application you also make use of `WL.nativePage.show`, which transitions you to a native page, and in there you have that other functionality written in Java?

The `WLCookieExtractor` class statically holds the cookies, so you can share them across other requests in your application.
In iOS you have the method `getCookies` and in Android you have the public field `cookies`.

After your request you can simply access this field and see what it holds. It should hold all that is required. When you transition from the Hybrid webview to the native page, shared automatically with anything invoked via WL.NativePage.

I have also opened a documentation defect to enhance it.

Comment: Thanks Idan. Put it this way. We have created a (native) login page along with some native features. Then inside this native application is our HTML5 app which is an activity and extends WLDroidGap. We switch between the 2 by using `Activity.startActivity()`. So what we'd like to find out is, when we authenticate natively, how do we share the cookies with our extended `WLDroidGap`. Hope that makes sense. Please note that we don't currently utilize `WL.nativePage.show()`

Comment: So you're not exactly writing a Hybrid Worklight application as the question says; this comment should be the base of your original question. Please update it.

Comment: coming back to this question, we now implemented the native login page and have utilised `WL.nativePage.show()`. We are using WLClients invokeProcedure method and are accessing a protected procedure which returns a challenge that is handled inside our challenge handler. This is all done in Native code. Once we are logged in and get data, we are returning to the HTML5 code as per the documentation and can see our HTML5 app. The `WLCookieExtractor.cookies` field is null, and the requests coming from Javascript don't have the same cookies that the Native client has. How do we share the cookies?

Comment: So as it turns in Worklight 6.0.0.x cookie sharing between hybrid and native views was not possible (it was not a "two-way street"). This will be fully handled by Worklight in a future release.

Comment: do we know what release this is likely to appear in?

Comment: I obviously cannot answer that. Soon.